# Spring Security Principal Incorrectly Persisted

Tags: spring, spring-security

My web application is using Spring Security and everything seems fine except for one thing. Once I authenticate a user in one browser they are always authenticated.  If I close all instances of a certain broswer (for example Chrom) and open a new instance, I'm not prompted for authentication and proceed directly to the secured resouce. If I bounce my local dev server then I'm prompted as expected.  I need a sticky session but not that sticky. Any ideas why Spring doesn't prompt me again after closing all browser instances? I'm using spring-security*3.1.0.M1 and spring-core-3.0.5.RELEASE.  Thanks for the assistance!

security context file(removed the xml and schema definitions):

```
<global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled">
</global-method-security>
<http security="none" pattern="/services/rest-api/1.0/**" />
<http security="none" pattern="/preregistered/**" />
<http access-denied-page="/auth/denied.html">
    <intercept-url
        pattern="/**/*.xhtml"
        access="ROLE_NONE_GETS_ACCESS" />
    <intercept-url
        pattern="/auth/**"
        access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS,ROLE_USER" />
    <intercept-url
        pattern="/auth/*"
        access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS" />
     <intercept-url
        pattern="/**"
        access="ROLE_USER" />
    <form-login
        login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check.html"
        login-page="/auth/login.html"
        default-target-url="/registered/home.html"
        authentication-failure-url="/auth/login.html?_dc=45" />
    <logout logout-url="/auth/logout.html"
            logout-success-url="/" />
    <anonymous username="guest" granted-authority="ROLE_ANONYMOUS"/>
    <remember-me user-service-ref="userManager" key="valid key here"/>
</http>
<!-- Configure the authentication provider -->
<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userManager">
            <password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder" />
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

Comment: @colin That's what remember me service is supposed to do. Do you see the same behavior when you do logout instead of closing browser?

Comment: @Ritesh Im unable to get the logout to work.  I posted my issue here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5321982/spring-security-log-out-failure-http-bio-8080-exec-5-java-lang-stackoverflowerr