# Spring Security Log Out Failure http-bio-8080"-exec-5" java.lang.StackOverflowError

Tags: spring-security

I've seen a few examples of Spring's logout and it seems a bit abstract to me.  I have a link with the href="appcontext_path/auth/logout.html". The examples I've seen don't have a psychical logout.html in the auth folder.  So I'm assuming this is a behind the scenes task.  I want to be able to click a log out link that invalidates the session and any associated cookies and navigates to the login page (auth/login.html).  When I try the below config, I get a Exception in thread ""http-bio-8080"-exec-5" java.lang.StackOverflowError

```
<global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled">
</global-method-security>
<http security="none" pattern="/javax.faces.resource/**" />
<http security="none" pattern="/services/rest-api/1.0/**" />
<http security="none" pattern="/preregistered/**" />
<http access-denied-page="/auth/denied.html">
    <intercept-url
        pattern="/**/*.xhtml"
        access="ROLE_NONE_GETS_ACCESS" />
    <intercept-url
        pattern="/auth/*"
        access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS" />
     <intercept-url
        pattern="/registered/*"
        access="ROLE_USER" />
    <form-login
        login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check.html"
        login-page="/auth/login.html"
        default-target-url="/registered/home.html"
        authentication-failure-url="/auth/login.html" />
    <logout logout-url="/auth/logout.html"
            logout-success-url="/auth/login.html" />
    <anonymous username="guest" granted-authority="ROLE_ANONYMOUS"/>
    <remember-me user-service-ref="userManager" key="ddddd23aferq3f3qrf"/>
</http>
<!-- Configure the authentication provider -->
<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userManager">
            <password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder" />
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the tag `<logout/>` and use `j_spring_security_logout` as a link to the logout functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You have error in configuration `<logout logout-url="/auth/logout.html" logout-success-url="/auth/login.html" />` causes Spring logout filter that catches `logout.html` requests to `logout.html` (i.e. to itself) - and this causes SOE.

You should use different URLs for `logout-url` and `logout-success-url`.

Comment: The logout-url and the logout-success-url are different.  I don't understand your comment.  I thought the logout-url property just says once going to the auth/logout.html page the logout process is triggered.